# WordPress theme requires PHP v >=8.1 - How to a dd different PHP version to docker-composer

Tags: php, themes, docker

I'm new to docker and stumbling into a PHP issue with a WP theme (sage 9).

I can add a WordPress site, Database and phpmyadmin with no issues. But when visting the site, the below message displays

*Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0".*

The theme's composer only works when using PHP >=8.1.0.
I might be stating the obvious but I guess I need to use PHP >=8.1.0 to use the theme?

Below is the docker-compose.yml file

```
# version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: WP_name
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      # - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dbname
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      # WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX : ''
    ports:
      - 8081:80

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql_WP
    restart: always
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    #volumes:
      #  - ./database_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/exampledb.sql
    volumes:
       - ./schema:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT: password

  php:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
```

The PHP build dockerfile at the bottom of docker-compose.yml (Dockerfile) contains:

```
FROM php:8.1.23-fpm-alpine
```

Can someone please advise on how I can add PHP version >=8.1.13 to the site (as an image?) in docker?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the wordpress image to the below works

```
wordpress:6.3.1-php8.1-apache
```

Full docker-compose.yml file

```
# version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql_WP
    restart: always
    command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    # volumes:
    #    - ./schema:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORT: password

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:6.3.1-php8.1-apache
    container_name: WP_name
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      # - ./src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dbname
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      # WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX : ''
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```

Comment: I'm surprised the 'latest' image is PHP 8.0! It looks like just 'php8.1' would work too, unless you want to fix on WordPress version 6.3.1.